# How to I replace NULL with 0

Tags: python, pandas

I trying to replace NULL values to zero.

Using `rf['Pt 1']=rf['Pt 1'].fillna(0,inplace=True)` only helps to replace blank with 0.

But I still did not manage to replace `NULL` (i.e. the string `"Null"`, not a `None` value) with zero.

Anyone know how to go about replacing NULL with 0 ?

```
rf['Pt 1']=rf['Pt 1'].fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

My output result:

```
    Pt 1
    0
    NULL
    990
    991
    996
    995
    992
    992
    992
    993
    993
    993
    991
    991
    989
    NULL
    NULL
    NULL
    995
    993
```

Comment: You need to post a [mcve].

Comment: you can use [pandas.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart so sorry about this. Will improve the quality of my post in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that my output is NULL instead of Nan is due to the CSV file that I reading already prefix Nan as Null and I realized there a white space before NULL.

The below will work:

```
  rf=rf.replace(to_replace=" NULL",value=0)
```

Comment: If your question is solved, please accept your own answer so others know it is closed and solved.

Comment: @ItamarMushkin can help me close it ? I can only close it after 2 days.

Comment: I didn't remember that you have to wait two days. And for a good reason - give time to answerers, maybe someone will have a better, more complete answer. Otherwise, accept you own.

Answer (score 5):

Use Pandas

I hope `DataFrame.fillna()` will work. [Refer Documentation for more insight](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Comment: OP specifically said they need to fill another value, not `None`

Answer (score 1):

There are two alternatives:

```
table_name['col_name'] = table_name['col_name'].fillna(0)
```

or

```
table_name['col_name'].fillna(0, inplace = True)
```